# defining a rudimentary alloc function

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation

this is an example in K&R book **ch5** , this example is to define alloc function i got it but i stuck and failed to understand why he return old pointer and in the first statement `allocp += n;` he increment allocp then he decrement it `allocp - n` this is my first Question, also I can't understand if condition block

```
if(condition is true)
 do something;
```

when he writes return statement so if role will be finished and return old pointer , and perform one cycle . and can't reach to all n segments .
my second Question **is that true to write return inside if rather than writes it out of if block ?** 
this is the whole code

```
#define ALLOCSIZE 1000
static char allocbuf[ALLOCSIZE];
static char *allocp = allocbuf;
char *alloc(int n)
{
    if(allocbuf + ALLOCSIZE - allocp >= n ) // it fits
    {
        allocp += n;
        return allocp - n; // old p 
    }else
        return 0;

}
```

Comment: You need to take a pencil and piece of paper and draw what's going on. Then you should understand it by your own. Concerning your second question: yes you can return from a function from anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is supposedly allocating memory, and returns a pointer to the allocated segment, while `allocp` is just used to keep track of how much memory that has been allocated.

It is ok to return from inside an `if` statement, though as a rule of thumb one should try to avoid multiple return statements from the same function.

You could rewrite the function as something like this, which is perhaps clearer:

```
#include <stdint.h>

#define ALLOCSIZE 1000
static uint8_t allocbuf [ALLOCSIZE];
static size_t alloc_size = 0;

uint8_t* alloc (size_t n)
{
  uint8_t* result = NULL; 

  if(alloc_size + n < ALLOCSIZE)
  {
    result = allocbuf + alloc_size;
    alloc_size += n;
  }

  return result;
}
```

Comment: my fairly Q is when i reach return statement the result is returned to its caller and has finished although if my input is 5 to reserve 5 segments then it will increment allocp +1 then return last allocp and the alloc fu is stoped . 
in your code you will return the last address of reserved segments ?

Answer (score 0):

The code snippet you have posted does -

1. Has a static buffer of 1000 bytes represented by

   ```
   static uint8_t allocbuf [ALLOCSIZE];
   ```
2. When a user asks for "n" bytes via the alloc() call, it checks if there is enough memory available (it the request fits within the 1000 bytes) and returns a pointer pointing to the start of this allocation request. (there can be multiple allocation requests).
3. The 2nd time you call alloc, you see how allocp pointer is already pointing to the (end address + 1)th byte of the last alloc request? (If you do not see it, I suggest you read what the static keyword does) So, your new allocation starts at allocp if it is permissible. Otherwise, it returns NULL.

If you are very new to programming, as [Jabberwocky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/898348/jabberwocky) has suggested, have a pencil and paper and do the math over multiple alloc calls. You can even use printf statements in alloc() and print allocp value before it returns, over multiple iterations and see what happens.

And yes, it is ok to return from anywhere within the function.